# how to implement multiple level of admin in django?

Tags: python, django

I need a superadmin_A for the whole project and that superadmin_A can create superadmin_A and admin_A for the project.

Superadmin_A can create a company Q and can create superadmin_B for the company Q.

Superadmin_B can create admin_B and superadmin_B level for the company Q

Now admin_B and Super Admin_B can login only for the company assigned to him and can create/edit Articles, Member etc of the company.

I am doing this in django 2.

- Superadmin_A - can cerate admin_A and superadmin_A for the site
- Admin_A - can create only company
- Superadmin_A - can create a company Q  superadmin_B for company Q
- Superadmin_B - can create Admin_B and other company details -eg Articles, Members etc.
- Admin_B - can create deatils of comapny Q eg. Article, Member etc.

Levels of admin -

- A - admin for site/project
- B - admin for a comapny

Hierarchy

- Superadmin_A
- Admin_A
- SuperAdmin_B
- admin_B

Can anyone please guide me on how I go about implementing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean changing authentication for specific user groups? or want to divide actual admin web sites?

Comment: I want different admin sites for diffrent admins. for  A and B level and diffrent authentication. please remeber company is associated with B level.

Comment: If using `groups`, you can show/hide admin menus and authentication. But if you want to make totally different admin stie, I guess you have to make your own.

Comment: How should I proceed to make one??

Comment: You can use `AdminSites`. I will make answer

Answer (score 0):

You can register models for different `AdminSites`. like below

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite

class FirstAdminSite(AdminSite):
    pass
    #or overwrite some methods for different functionality

firstadmin = FirstAdminSite(name="firstadmin")
```

Then, you can use this `firstadmin` after register in `urls.py`.

```
from project_name.admin import admin, user_site
from project_name.admin import firstadmin
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^firstadmin/', include(firstadmin.urls)),
```

In django docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects - you can see many adminsite objects that you can customize.